# Airflow doesn't recognize DAG scheduling

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm trying to make weekly, monthly airflow schedules but it's not working. Could anyone report what may be happening? If I make weekly, monthly scheduling, it stays still, as if it were turned off. No error message, simply does not execute. I sent a code example to demonstrate how I'm scheduling ... is there any other way to do this scheduling?

```
import airflow
import os
import six
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow import AirflowException
from airflow.models import BaseOperator
from airflow.utils.decorators import apply_defaults
from airflow.operators.slack_operator import SlackAPIPostOperator

default_args = {
    'owner': 'bexs-data',
    'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(0),
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': ['airflow@apache.org'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'depends_on_past': False,
    # If a task fails, retry it once after waiting
    # at least 5 minutes
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'on_failure_callback': slack_msg
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id=nm_dag,
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval='51 18 * * 4', 
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=60)
)
```

Comment: `"..but it's not working. Could anyone report what may be happening?"` that is very vague. Please be more descriptive as to what observation / error you are encountering. Similarly `"..daily, monthly airflow schedules.."` also doesn't tell anything

Comment: The problem is indeed simple! If I make weekly, monthly scheduling, it stays still, as if it were turned off. No error message, simply does not execute. I sent a code example to demonstrate how I'm scheduling ... is there any other way to do this scheduling?

Comment: If I make a schedule run every 10 minutes it works! From weekly onwards no ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is documentation around not doing the following:
`'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(0),` because in this way there will never be a 1 week interval that has passed since your start date, which means the first interval doesn't close, and the first run doesn't get scheduled.

Suggestion: pick a fixed day on a day-of-the-week 4 (Thursday?) from last week as your `start_date`.

Airflow [will accept a `datetime` or a string](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/88989200a66291580088188f06a6db503ac823e2/airflow/models/dag.py#L251-L271). Use `airflow.utils.timezone`'s `datetime` for a non-UTC schedule. For example, either:

```
default_args = {
  'owner': 'your-unix-user-id-or-ldap-etc',
  'start_date': '2018-1-1',
...
}
```

or

```
from airflow.utils.timezone import datetime

default_args = {
  'owner': 'your-unix-user-id-or-ldap-etc',
  'start_date': datetime(2018, 1, 1),
...
}
```